# getting incompatible error while trying to assign a function to on click event

Tags: delphi, events

I have a button on my form on clicking the button the form caption will get change.below is my work out code .

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;

    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure setcaption(Sender: TObject);
  private
      { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
 { TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.setcaption (Sender: TObject);
begin
    ((sender as tbutton).Parent as tform).Caption := 'Success...';
end;


procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.OnClick := setcaption(sender);
end;
```

getting error

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(38): Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'
```

Please correct my mistake, i am new to this concept...

Comment: Much easier for IDE to set this up in .dfm file. Also replace `((sender as tbutton).Parent as tform).Caption := 'Success...';` with `Caption := 'Success...';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following:

```
Button1.OnClick := setcaption;
```

Please check the types on the left and right sides in your assignment statement. Left side is of `TNotifyEvent` type. This implies what your expression at the right side has to be of the same type, eg: is a `function` that returns `TNotifyEvent`-typed value. Obviously, your `procedure` call does not do that.

Recommended reading: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Procedural_Types#Procedural_Types_in_Statements_and_Expressions